# redirect htaccess with php variables and rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i'm trying to redirect this url:

```
/bla.php?language=en
```

to ->

```
/bla/en/
```

i also need to bring the php variable language=en

so far i achieve this

```
RewriteRule ^bla/language/([^/]*)$ /bla.php?language=$1 [L]
```

this creates this url

```
/bla/language/en/
```

i want to remove or if that isn't possible shorten "language"

also i want this url /bla.php?language=en to 301 redirect to the shortened url "/bla/en/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `/language/`:

```
RewriteRule ^bla/([^/]+)/?$ /bla.php?language=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

For your 301 requirement:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+bla\.php\?language=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /bla/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't bring the php variable language=en

Comment: Actually it does. How are you accessing variable in PHP? You should use $_GET['language']

Comment: that is how i access the variable. echo $_GET['language']; shows nothing
also my rewrite 

    RewriteRule ^bla/language/([^/]*)$ /bla.php?language=$1 [L]

doesn't bring the variable

Comment: What URL are you using to test this rule? Also do post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: yes finally it works, don't know what went wrong
I use - instead of /
it works now