# clean URL's with htaccess from get request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite some url's from a $_GET request with .htaccess with no luck.

How's the syntax for (left side = original url, right side = new url)

```
/?lang=en   --->  /en/
/index?lang=en ----> /en/index
/pageA?lang=de  ----> /de/pageA
/pageB/lang=es ---->  /es/pageB
```

Can this be done without editing manually all the pages and get requests in the .htaccess file?

Thanks in advance for helping.

**EDIT**

This is my code so far to eliminate the .php at the end in the URL

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

It's only the code which is working.

Comment: What are `index?lang=en`, `pageA?lang=de`? Are they directory? Show your current .htaccess contents.

Comment: index, pageA, pageB, pageC are all pages. The files are displayed in the root directory

Comment: You are likely thinking of this backwards.  I assume what you want is to be able to enter in a URI like `/en/` and have that forward to your server script with query string like `lang=en` right?  So you actually silently rewrite the clean URL to a backend script.

Comment: @MikeBrant :yes; when the user types the url like in your example it shoud be redirect to the real url but without showing the redirect in the url. Also, when the user make the $_GET request via the switching language menu, the user should be redirected to the fake "folder"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think there should be an internally + an externally redirect.

Comment: So you need the URL in the address bar to change also?

Comment: Yes, the url should appear clean

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^(([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)?(\?|\/)lang=([A-Za-z]{2}))$ redirect.php?page=$1 [L]
```

EDIT:

If you want to redirect to the clean URL, then what you probably want to do is make one central php page to go to.  From that page, determine where you want to go and then do a `header("Location: ".$real_page); exit;`

Here's an example:

```
<?php

// REDIRECT.PHP

$page = $_GET['page'];

$real_page = preg_replace('/([-A-Z0-9_]+)?(\?|\/)lang=([A-Z]{2})/i', '/$3/$1', $page);

header("Location: ".$real_page);
exit;
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to keep it all withing .htaccess and not mess with the PHP redirect, you can use the `[R=302]` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)?(\?|\/)lang=([A-Za-z]{2})$ /$3/$1 [R=302]
```

That should actually change the URL for you.

Comment: Doesn't work; maybe there should be an THE_REQUEST inside, but i don't know where to put it in

Comment: If it's not working, try moving it up above your other RewriteRules.  I've edited my post to reflect how to handle it if you also want clean URLs in addition to redirecting.

Comment: But maybe it's possibile to do it only with .htaccess, without upsetting the whole php code? If yes, i'm searching to do it only with .htaccess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your second edit looks correct for me, but it's still not "redirecting" to the fake folder.

Comment: Have done it. I also tried to modify [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229121/redirect-htaccess-with-php-variables-and-rewrite-url) solution, but it's also not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48712/discussion-between-quixrick-and-someone33)